# Facebook PSID/ASID matching

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to match users of my chatbot accross different Messenger pages using the Facebook matching API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/<user_psid>/ids_for_pages?access_token=<page_access_token>
```

I'm having trouble to get a success response from the Graph API and I keep on receiving the error:

> (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.

The error is unclear and I cannot find an explanation in the doc. I suspect it's related to a lack of permission but it's not mentionned anywhere in the doc which one is required for such a call.

The page of which the access token is used is added to my Facebook business account. I also tried to make the call using the app access token but I get the same error (the app is also added to the business account).

Is this problem related to missing permission? If yes, which one should be requested from Facebook?

EDIT:
As suggested by CBroe, it could have been related to the 48h review following the first API call but after waiting past the time window the error persists.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching lists clear requirements for each use case, have you verified all of them are met?

Comment: Also, have you taken into account that it says _“Your initial call to the API may trigger an app review that can take approximately 48 hours to complete.”_ in the introduction?

Comment: I've have verified requirements but the 48h verification may be the issue. I'll wait until tomorrow to say, thanks for the reminder

Comment: It's more than 48h and the error persists. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: But the basic requirements are fulfilled - you have a business set up, and have your apps connected to it? And if your app has not been through all the necessary reviews yet, then it will probably only work for users with a role in the app.